# How to change mute/unmute button?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ios

I'm saving music in libgdx preference, the following code works perfectly but if you enter the settings again you'd see the initial `button up` regardless if the sound is muted or not.

```
TextureAtlas buttonsAtlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/dialogButtons.pack");
textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("music.down");
textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("muteMusic.up");
button.addListener(new InputListener() {
 public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
  return true;
 }
 public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
  setMusicplaying(!musicplaying);
  if (getMusicplaying() == false)
   playMusic.stop();
  else playMusic.play();
 }
});
```

I tried to do this, it works perfecly but doesn't switch the button, when the user is clicking on it, it only switches when the user closes the dialog

```
if (getMusicplaying() == true) {
textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("music.down");
textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("muteMusic.up");}
if (getMusicplaying() == false) {
  textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("muteMusic.up");
  textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("music.down");}
```

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences ?

Comment: @realUser404 yes that but what I don't know how to do, is how to save the `pressed button state`. right now, when I enter the settings, the button shows in its original state, whether it's pressed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer since it may help someone, i got it from libgdx forums

```
if (getMusicplaying() == false)
 button.setChecked(true)
```

no need for more code, that's it.